# I want to add serial number in tow separate loop in angular

Tags: angular

**I want to add serial number of tow sperate ngFor loop code is given below**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sr</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <ng-container #atvalue>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; let c = count">
    <td>{{i+1}} {{c}}</td>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
  </ng-container>
   <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <td>{{atvalue.childElementCount.length +1}}</td>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I don't know this is the right way for this but it solves my problem**

```
    <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sr</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; let c = count" >
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let item of items2; let i = index">
    <td>{{items.length+i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let item of items3; let i = index">
    <td>{{items2.length+items2.length+i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**and here is the output of my code**

Sr  Name
1   First
2   Second
3   Third
4   Forth
5   eight
6   nine
7   Helo1
8   list2
9   list9